# Excel VBA: How to programably turn on Snap-To-Grid

Tags: vba, excel

How to turn on snap to grid in Excel using VBA ?

[image]

Comment: Google "How to turn on snap to grid in Excel using VBA" - first result http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/vba-code-to-turn-on-snap-to-grid/4561543e-6157-44a6-afd9-ad257c00de55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=549).Execute` (tested up to excel 2010)

Comment: Works in Excel 2013

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, first checking whether Snap-grid is already enabled or not

```
 Sub Snap_to_grid()
    With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=549)
        If Not (.Enabled) Then: .Execute
    End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted don't work in Office 365. Solution for 365:

```
Sub TurnOnSnapToGrid
    If Not Application.CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SnapToGrid") Then
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SnapToGrid")
    End If
End Sub
```